# Firefox Addon: Get Sync Device Name

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a simple Addon for Firefox.

There's an option for user to set up a Device Name in [Firefox Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=what-firefox-sync)

[image: Device Name]

How to get that name "My PC" in the Addon code?

It's a really simple extension

**main.js**

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var deviceName = what.what?
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably using weave service but I can't figure it out:

```
var WeaveService = Cc["@mozilla.org/weave/service;1"].getService(Ci.nsISupports);
    // Referencing Weave.Service will implicitly initialize sync, and we don't
    // want to force that - so first check if it is ready.
/* WeaveService object holds these:
enabled:true
fxAccountsEnabled:true
ready:true
*/
if (WaveService.ready) {

}
```

So I cheated and read pref value:

```
var clientEngineName = Services.prefs.getCharPref('services.sync.client.name');
```

Comment: This might help: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/sync/aboutSyncTabs.js#207-246